# Why is my store not updating when I use a deep watch?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store

The deep watcher I set for this component does not update the store when I change the value of the text field. I cannot find a way to properly change the store object's (profile) key/value pair (groupName: *string*)

**Profile.vue Element**:

```
<v-text-field v-model="profileData.groupName" label="Group Name"></v-text-field>
```

**Profile.vue JS**:

```
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Profile",
  created() {
    this.profileData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getProfile()));
    console.log(this.profileData);
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapGetters(["getProfile"]),
    ...mapMutations(["setProfile"])
  },
  watch: {
    profileData: {
      handler(value) {
        this.setProfile(value);
      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
};
```

**build.js** (*Module of store.js*):

```
const state = {
    profile: {
        "groupName": "Happy group",
        "groupNumber": "9999999999",
        "groupContact": "Bob Ross"
    }
};

const getters = {
    getProfile: (state) => state.profile,
};

const actions = { };

const mutations = { 
    setProfile: (state, profile) => (state.profile = profile)
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
}
```

I'm not sure why the state is not updating. Does anyone know?

Thank you for reading

Comment: (1) Assigning an object does not copy it, so `pp` is actually referring to the same object in your store (and you should still see the Vuex mutation warnings upon editing). (2) Try a deep watcher on `pp` that calls `setProfile` with the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **shouldn't bind the state's variable** like you did here: `v-model="profile.groupName"` (in pratice you are mutating a prop outside vuex mutation and you are probably getting some console warning about that).

So you can copy `getProfile` value to a local variable (vue's `data()`) and dispatch an **action** to update `profile` in state when you want (according to a handler or whatever).

Comment: I tried editing it to use a copy, it did not work. Added that to the original post.

Comment: I tried using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.getProfile())) and its still parsing it as the store object ```{__ob__: Observer}``` (https://i.imgur.com/FX5vOJV.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's because Vue allows you to modify vuex state directly when not in strict mode. If you enable strict mode, any mutation outside a mutation handler will throw an error.

```
export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
  strict: true
}
```

The Vuex guide mentions it [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html). You could also enable it only for development

```
strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
```

Comment: I added the strict mode. It's not restricting me from mutating the state even when I only map the getters.

Comment: Does it throw error's in the console when you directly update the state ?

Comment: No errors in the console after directly updating the state.

Comment: i set it up wrong. got the error: `Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.`

Comment: Great, It may not restrict you from updating the state, but you should get error warnings about improper mutations.

Comment: Awesome. It seems the problem is because whenever I try to create a local copy of the store data, it copies the actual store object into a variable that I name; so whenever I mutate ```localCopy.groupName``` I'm actually changing ```this.$store.state.build.profile.groupName```. Not sure how to fix this as stringifying and parsing doesn't seem to be copying the object correctly.

Comment: Rather than using the $store object, you should use a vuex getter to access the stored data.

Comment: I am using the getter to access the store object. I have a bit of a solve going on, update above.